# Python Rest API - looping through dictionary object

Tags: python, json, rest, dictionary

Python newbie here

I am querying an API and get a json string like this:

```
{
  "human": [
    {
      "h": 310,
      "prob": 0.9588886499404907,
      "w": 457,
      "x": 487,
      "y": 1053
    },
    {
      "h": 283,
      "prob": 0.8738606572151184,
      "w": 455,
      "x": 1078,
      "y": 1074
    },
    {
      "h": 216,
      "prob": 0.8639854788780212,
      "w": 414,
      "x": 1744,
      "y": 1159
    },
    {
      "h": 292,
      "prob": 0.7896996736526489,
      "w": 442,
      "x": 2296,
      "y": 1088
    }
  ]
}
```

I figured out how to get a dict object in python

`json_data = json.loads(response.text)`

But I am not sure how to loop through the dict object. I have tried this, but this prints out the key repeatedly, how do I access the parent object and child objects?

```
   for data in json_data:
        print data
        for sub in data:
            print sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following examples:

```
print json_data['human']
>> [
      {
        "h": 310,
        "prob": 0.9588886499404907,
        "w": 457,
        "x": 487,
        "y": 1053
      },
      {
        "h": 283,
        "prob": 0.8738606572151184,
        "w": 455,
        "x": 1078,
        "y": 1074
      },
      .
      .
  ]


for data in json_data['human']:
    print data
>> {
     "h": 310,
     "prob": 0.9588886499404907,
     "w": 457,
     "x": 487,
     "y": 1053
   } 

   {
     "h": 283,
     "prob": 0.8738606572151184,
     "w": 455,
     "x": 1078,
     "y": 1074
    }
.
.


for data in json_data['human']:
    print data['h']
>> 310
   283
```

In order to loop through the keys:

```
for type_ in json_data:
    print type_
    for location in json_data[type_]:
        print location
```

`type_` is used to avoid Python's built-it `type`. You can use whatever name you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, but the "key" could be different types e.g. "vehicle", "human","building" etc., how do I loop through the keys and for each of the keys loop through locations? Sorry if I wasn't clear in my original question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to use iteritems to get the keys and values from your dictionary like this:

```
for k, v in json_data.iteritems():
    print "{0} : {1}".format(k, v)
```

If you instead meant to traverse the dictionary recursively, try something like this:

```
def traverse(d):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            traverse(v)
        else:
            print "{0} : {1}".format(k, v)

traverse(json_data)
```

Comment: For Python 3, use `.items()` instead of `.iteritems()`.